# Using Meteor With another Programming Language

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, meteor

I work on a new project and using `Meteor` will be so helpfull in my project but I'm litel bit confused if that I can mix between `Meteor` And `ASP.net or PHP`. 
My idea is using `ASP.net Or PHP` for the backend office (Member page, Admin page ...) and `Meteor` For my Home page( it has Vote systeme, Posting new Topic ...) and I think that's `Meteor` can handle those action in perfect way. 
So my question is Can this be done?

Comment: The platform is called Meteor, not Meteor.js. I edited your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Meteor uses NodeJS under the hood which is a server side javascript runtime. That means that the backend and frontend is providet by the meteor server and both parts . You can do network calls over http to other PHP or ASP servers, but you don't need to mix the languages.

On of the meteor principles is: "One Language. Write both the client and the server parts of your interface in JavaScript." (http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples)

Answer (score 3):

While one of the principles of Meteor is "One Language. Write both the client and the server parts of your interface in JavaScript.", moving to an all JavaScript solution may not be practical for all situations.

The good news is that Meteor uses an underlying protocol called DDP, to manage the communication necessary for the Publish/Subscribe pattern used to keep your client side collections up to date.

I expect that the protocol will eventually be implemented in all major languages, meaning you can use the language of your choice on the server side and javasScript with Meteor the client.

So to answer your question, yes it can be done. Doing a quick Google search I managed to find https://github.com/sonyarouje/DDPClient.NET

If that does not work exactly as you require, you can always implement the protocol youself in the any language. In the words of the Meteor team

> We'd love to see DDP clients for Objective C, Java, Ruby, Python, PHP,
>   and so forth.

Here are some other links that may interest you:

- http://meteor.com/get-involved
- http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-ddp-client